# Converting from QGIS to Illustrator?

Tags: qgis, illustrator

I need help converting a download from Geofabrik to Illustrator. It had worked for me earlier, but I can't remember what I did, and now it doesn't.

- I downloaded a country from Geofabrik (because city wasn't available) and now I want to extract three different cities (roads only) for an art project
- its an 11GB .osm file
- I Go to: Vector (menu) → OpenStreetMap → Import Topology from XML.
- Then I get a .osm.db file
- Then I do Vector (menu) → OpenStreetMap → Export Topology to SpatiaLite.... (and select the .osm.db file)
- I select poly lines and my highway/road/lane tags
- But at this state QGIS goes into a freeze (I have 12GB RAM).
  What now?

---

Will try those options.
Meanwhile, the export seems to have happened, but the Map Canvas is blank. Anything I should know here?

My newly exported file is a new layer, has 1943641 feature counts etc, but MapCanvas is blank. How do I see the map, zoom to my area, and create a New Print Composer?

Comment: are you trying to export Topology  oms sqlite data to the same sqlite db ?

Comment: I was just following instructions from a WIKI

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect a country-sized 12Gb OSM import to take a while.

You could see if your city is one of those available [from mapzen metro](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/), that might cut the size down.

Or you could do a custom extract for a given area using [bbbike](https://extract.bbbike.org/), you may need to change the format from the default (protocol buffers) to Gzipped OSM XML, then unzip the download.